# Solr 9 - Jackson deserialization fails with java.security.AccessControlException

Tags: solr, jackson, jackson-databind

I am new to Solr and trying to create a module containing an implementation of
UpdateRequestProcessor where I am using processAdd method for hooking into the Solr document add/update lifecycle.

This module is dependent on 3rd party libraries like Apache httpcomponents, Jackson etc. which are already provided by Solr, so, when I try to add a document to Solr, the request comes to processAdd method where I make a call to Algolia using Algolia SDK which internally uses Apache httpcomponents, Jackson etc. and finally deserialize the response using Jackson.

For the fact that Solr is running under SecurityManager and security.policy file has this permission defined

```
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessDeclaredMembers";
```

Not sure what is causing this, Solr or Jackson or Algolia SDK. I did not find any previous issues where Jackson(in Solr, under a SecurityManager) is involved and causing a security exception so raising this issue.

This is the full exception trace I get while Algolia SDK deserializes the response using Jackson.

```
    2023-07-22 13:49:22.818 ERROR (qtp371397455-22) [ x:algolia] c.a.c.b.s.p.AlgoliaUpdateRequestProcessor java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers") => com.algolia.search.exceptions.AlgoliaRuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")
    at com.algolia.search.exceptions.LaunderThrowable.launder(LaunderThrowable.java:38)
com.algolia.search.exceptions.AlgoliaRuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")
    at com.algolia.search.exceptions.LaunderThrowable.launder(LaunderThrowable.java:38) ~[?:?]
    at com.algolia.search.exceptions.LaunderThrowable.await(LaunderThrowable.java:19) ~[?:?]
    at com.algolia.search.SearchIndex.saveObject(SearchIndex.java:678) ~[?:?]
    at com.algolia.connector.bridge.solr.service.impl.AlgoliaServiceImpl.createRecord(AlgoliaServiceImpl.java:48) ~[?:?]
    at com.algolia.connector.bridge.solr.plugin.AlgoliaUpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(AlgoliaUpdateRequestProcessor.java:71) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory$AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java:535) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:111) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:111) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:111) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:111) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory$1.processAdd(FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory.java:71) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:111) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory$DefaultValueUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory.java:82) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader$1.update(JavabinLoader.java:123) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$StreamingCodec.readOuterMostDocIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:342) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$StreamingCodec.readIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:286) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readObject(JavaBinCodec.java:338) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:283) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$StreamingCodec.readNamedList(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:236) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readObject(JavaBinCodec.java:303) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:283) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinCodec.java:193) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:126) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.parseAndLoadDocs(JavabinLoader.java:135) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.load(JavabinLoader.java:74) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:102) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:84) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:224) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2893) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.executeCoreRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:871) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:567) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.dispatch(SolrDispatchFilter.java:250) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(SolrDispatchFilter.java:218) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletUtils.traceHttpRequestExecution2(ServletUtils.java:257) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletUtils.rateLimitRequest(ServletUtils.java:227) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:213) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:195) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:210) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:527) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578) ~[jetty-security-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:223) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1570) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:221) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1384) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:176) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:484) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1543) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:174) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1306) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:149) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:228) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:141) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:301) ~[jetty-rewrite-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:822) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:563) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$0(HttpChannel.java:505) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:762) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:497) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.run(HttpChannel.java:457) ~[jetty-server-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:416) ~[jetty-util-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:385) ~[jetty-util-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:272) ~[jetty-util-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.produce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:194) ~[jetty-util-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Connection.produce(HTTP2Connection.java:208) ~[http2-common-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Connection.onFillable(HTTP2Connection.java:155) ~[http2-common-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Connection$FillableCallback.succeeded(HTTP2Connection.java:378) ~[http2-common-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100) ~[jetty-io-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53) ~[jetty-io-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:416) ~[jetty-util-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:385) ~[jetty-util-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:272) ~[jetty-util-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.lambda$new$0(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:140) ~[jetty-util-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:411) ~[jetty-util-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:969) ~[jetty-util-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1194) ~[jetty-util-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1149) ~[jetty-util-10.0.15.jar:10.0.15]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999) ~[?:?]
    at com.algolia.search.exceptions.LaunderThrowable.await(LaunderThrowable.java:17) ~[?:?]
    ... 90 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:897) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:322) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.checkMemberAccess(Class.java:2847) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2246) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector._findFields(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:73) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector._findFields(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:71) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector.collect(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:48) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector.collectFields(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass._fields(AnnotatedClass.java:370) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.fields(AnnotatedClass.java:342) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addFields(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:519) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collectAll(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:445) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getPropertyMap(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:405) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getProperties(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:247) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription._properties(BasicBeanDescription.java:164) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.findProperties(BasicBeanDescription.java:239) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._findCreatorsFromProperties(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:317) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._constructDefaultValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:271) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:222) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:262) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:151) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:415) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:350) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:654) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:4956) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4826) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3825) ~[?:?]
    at com.algolia.search.HttpTransport.lambda$executeWithRetry$0(HttpTransport.java:174) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1072) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:479) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183) ~[?:?]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here -

So, after trying placing the response deserialization call in a PrivilegedAction in Algolia SDK there is no more `java.security.AccessControlException: access denied` coming in.

```
try {
    return AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<CompletableFuture<TResult>>() {
        @Override
        public CompletableFuture<TResult> run() throws Exception {
            TResult result = Defaults.getObjectMapper().readValue(dataStream, type);
            logResponse(result);
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result);
        }
    });
} catch (PrivilegedActionException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```